# How to Program a Visual Studio 2010 Macro For accessing and editing specific Project files?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros, visual-studio-macros

i want to write a macro to put selected text to a specific XML file in my project. for example my path is ~/Pages/Dictionary/en.xml. and i want to put selected text from an aspx.cs file to en.xml file.
please guide me from where I should start. i can get the selected text. now i don't know how can i access a file content goto end of file(or another place in file) and insert some text according to selected text to it.

Answer (score 2):

To open the file, either use the tree path in the solution explorer or just use the full file path:

```
DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate()
DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem _
    ("{solutionname}\{projectname}\Pages\Dictionary\en.xml") _
    .Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)
DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.DoDefaultAction()
```

or

```
DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile _
    ("{projectpath}\Pages\Dictionary\en.xml")
DTE.ActiveDocument.Activate()
```

You did not mention whether this is for a single project and/or solution, so I do not know if just hard coding the items in the curly braces will suffice.

---

To insert the text at the end of the file, you can select the end of the document and just paste (e.g. if you used `Selection.Copy()`), or you can create an edit point and insert any text:

```
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfDocument()
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Paste()
```

or

```
Dim editPoint As EnvDTE.EditPoint
selection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection()
editPoint = selection.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint()
editPoint.Insert("any text" + vbLf)
```

I am not sure if the end of the file is the real location where you want to add text; if not, one can navigate the document with e.g. `StartOfLine()`, `LineUp()`, `WordRight()`, or other means to [control the code editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwda3d81%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you but i don't want to activate or view the target file. i want dynamically insert some text(for example an XML node as String to a XML file) and save the file without viewing, opening or activating it. is it possible to handle?!

Comment: Sure, though you did not mention that the file should not be opened in the editor: just code it using normal `System.IO.File` or `System.IO.Stream` calls and operations in your macro code…